# How to solve type mismatch error in Java when using generics with subclass mapping?

Tags: java, generics

I couldn't figure out why this code doesn't compile.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Generic {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //List of imputs
    List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();
    tests.add(new TestSub1());
    tests.add(new TestSub2());

    // Processors are in a Map
    Map<String, Processor<? extends Test>> testMaps = new HashMap<>();
    testMaps.put("Processor1", new Processor1());
    testMaps.put("Processor2", new Processor2());


    // Doesn't compile
    // java: incompatible types: Generic.Test cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Generic.Test
    tests.stream().filter(t -> t instanceof TestSub1)
            .forEach(test ->
                testMaps.get("Processor1").doWork(tests.get(0))
            );
}


static class Test {
}

static class TestSub1 extends Test {

}

static class TestSub2 extends Test {

}

static abstract class Processor<T extends Test> {

    abstract void doWork(T t);
}

// Processors can handle subclasses of Test
static  class Processor1 extends Processor<TestSub1> {

    @Override
    void doWork(TestSub1 testSub1) {
        System.out.println("processing testSub1");
    }
}

static  class Processor2 extends  Processor<TestSub2> {

    @Override
    void doWork(TestSub2 testSub2) {
        System.out.println("processing testSub2");
    }
}
}
```

I would like to have Processor per subclass of Test. I tried to cast tests.get(0) to TestSub1,but it doesn't work either. Is it possible to such thing or how can I make my processors type safe and generic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rightly getting a compile time error. You have a map with values of `? extends Test`, but the compiler doesn't know the exact types that the generic type of the Processor class will have. Then, you try to pass a superclass to the `doWork` method.

This will be best understood with an example:

```java
testMaps.get("Processor1").doWork(tests.get(1))
```

What if you pass an object of type `TestSub2` to the `doWork()` method? The `Processor1` can only handle classes of type `TestSub1`. It doesn't matter that in your code you earlier filter the results in such a way that only arguments of the appropriate type get to the method. The compiler doesn't know about this - it doesn't analyze the semantics of the code. Java is a strongly typed language, hence the compiler simply won't let you do this.

In this case, you might use a design pattern like the 'type-safe heterogeneous container' proposed by Joshua Bloch:

```java
class ProcessorTypeSafeContainer {
    private final Map<Class<? extends Test>, Processor<? extends Test>> processorRegistry = new HashMap<>();

    <T extends Test> void registerProcessor(Class<T> type, Processor<T> processor) {
        processorRegistry.put(type, processor);
    }

    void processTest(Test test) {
        Processor<? extends Test> processor = processorRegistry.get(test.getClass());
        if (processor == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No processor registered for type " + test.getClass());
        doWorkWithProcessor(processor, test);
    }

    private <T extends Test> void doWorkWithProcessor(Processor<T> processor, Test test) {
        processor.doWork((T) test);
    }
}
```

And then you may simply use it like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();
    tests.add(new TestSub1());
    tests.add(new TestSub2());

    ProcessorTypeSafeContainer container = new ProcessorTypeSafeContainer();
    container.registerProcessor(TestSub1.class, new Processor1());
    container.registerProcessor(TestSub2.class, new Processor2());

    tests.forEach(container::processTest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's tricky.
I managed to compile it by changing it that way, after many attempts.

```java
class Generic {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Generic generic = new Generic();
      generic.testing();
   }

   public void testing() {
      //List of imputs
      List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();
      tests.add(new TestSub1());
      tests.add(new TestSub2());

      // Processors are in a Map
      Map<String, Processor<? extends Test>> testMaps = new HashMap<>();
      testMaps.put("Processor1", new Processor1());
      testMaps.put("Processor2", new Processor2());


      // Doesn't compile
      // java: incompatible types: Generic.Test cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Generic.Test
      tests.stream().filter(t -> t instanceof TestSub1)
         .forEach(test ->
            testMaps.get("Processor1").doWork(tests.get(0))
         );
   }

   abstract public static class Test {
   }

   static class TestSub1 extends Test {
   }

   static class TestSub2 extends Test {
   }

   static abstract class Processor<T> {
      abstract void doWork(Test t);
   }

   // Processors can handle subclasses of Test
   static class Processor1 extends Processor<TestSub1> {
      @Override
      void doWork(Test testSub1) {
         System.out.println("processing testSub1");
      }
   }

   static class Processor2 extends  Processor<TestSub2> {
      @Override
      void doWork(Test testSub2) {
         System.out.println("processing testSub2");
      }
   }
}
```

Summarizing, it seems that I only changed your `void doWork(TestSub1 testSub1)` and `void doWork(TestSub2 testSub2)` by `void doWork(Test )` in fact.